# shell script to find file name from its path

Tags: shell

Hello i want a simple shell script that find the name of the file from a given path of the file. like

```
$path = "/var/www/html/test.php";
```

then i want to get value "test" in some variable. Also only .php files are present.I am using bash shell.
Thanks

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Try:

```
path="/var/www/html/test.php"
name=$(basename "$path" ".php")
echo "$name"
```

The quotes are only there to prevent problems when `$path` contains spaces.

Comment: we need to write the extention ?? ".php", what if we don't know the extention ? is there a way ?

Comment: @Hasni Try this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125281/how-do-i-remove-the-file-suffix-and-path-portion-from-a-path-string-in-bash

Answer (score 27):

Use the built in UNIX command:

```
basename "/var/www/html/test.php"
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the basename() function. It is buily in UNIX function

Answer (score 0):

```
string="/var/www/html/test.php"

oIFS="$IFS"; IFS='/' 
set -A str $string
IFS="$oIFS"

echo "strings count = ${#str[@]}"
len=${#str[@]}
pos=`expr $len - 1`
echo "file : ${str[$pos]}";
```

Output-

```
 strings count = 4
 file : test.php
```