# Convert many .pdf to .txt file in a directory

Tags: pdftotext

I have over a thousand files in a directory which I want to convert to text files. I use a code like the one below to first take out the spaces in the file names and then convert the files to text:

## !/bin/bash

```
   find . -name '*.pdf' | while read file;
   do
    target=`echo "$file" | sed 's/ /_/g'`;
    echo "Renaming '$file' to '$target'";
    mv "$file" "$target";
    chmod 777 *.pdf;
    pdftotext -layout  "$target"  "$target.txt";
   done;
```

This code however converts a file like **I love you.pdf** to **I_love_you.pdf.txt.** I want to remove the .pdf part of the final file extension.

Answer (score 1):

My preferred way of doing this is to use substitution to modify the extension:

```
pdftotext -layout "$target" "${target/%.pdf/.txt}"
```

The `%` there means to match only at the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this:

```
$target = "i_love_you.pdf"
```

therefore

```
$target.txt = "i_love_you.pdf.txt"
```

Note that [if you don't supply the second parameter to `pdftotext`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pdftotext), it will by default convert *file.pdf* to *file.txt*, which seems perfect for your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Use '`basename`' eg.

```
basename "i_love_you.pdf" ".pdf" returns "i_love_you"
```

See See [How do I remove the file suffix and path portion from a path string in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125281/how-do-i-remove-the-file-suffix-and-path-portion-from-a-path-string-in-bash)

Answer (score 0):

Another option might be:

find ./ -name "*.pdf" -exec pdftotext {} \;