# Figure out the destination of `ln -s` using script

Tags: shell, unix, zsh

First, here's the script I'm talking about:
https://github.com/Greduan/dotfiles/blob/master/scripts/symlinks.sh

Check line 20. It has the following content

```
dest = "$HOME/.`basename \"${source%.*}\"`"
```

Since I took this from another script, I have no idea what it actually does. I'm guessing what it does is if the source file is named `vimrc.vim.symlink` it'll output `.vimrc.vim`, correct?

If not correct, could you please explain what it does?

And could you please help me figure out how to make it so that if the file is `vimrc.vim.symlink`, how can I make it so that I can get `.vimrc`?

Please check the script so that you can understand what I'm talking about. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your analysis is correct. `${source%.*}` removes the `.*` suffix from `source`. The rest, `$HOME/.$(basename \"...\")` takes the basename of `source`, which removes all path from it, leaving only the file name and is placed after `$(HOME)/.`.

If you want to remove everything after (and including) the first dot, you can use `${source%%.*}` (with `%%` instead of `%`). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/125340/912144) gives you examples.