# rip off filename extension, if it is, one at time

Tags: regex, shell

I have filenames like `/dir/dir2/file.ext1.ext2` and I want to get filename without one extension:

```
/dir/dir2/file.xml.zip.sgn  => file.xml.zip
/dir/dir2/file.xml.zip      => file.xml
/dir/dir2/file.doc          => file
/dir/dir2/file              => file
file                        => file
```

would be great by `expr` , may be `grep -oP`

OK, I can start by `basename` to rip off dirs, but how to rip end-only optional extension ?

Comment: dirname is the answer...

Comment: Assuming your shell is `bash`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125281/how-do-i-remove-the-file-suffix-and-path-portion-from-a-path-string-in-bash

Comment: Thnks Andrew your answer is best

Answer (score 1):

```
x=/etc/lolf/logl/shells.ext1.ext2
y=${x/\/*\//} # rips dir ('basename' do the same)
echo ${y%.*}  # rips last ext
```

if lacks dirs or exts, it works anyway!

Anybody, could you do all in one pass?

thanx to Andrew Henle, see more at [How do I remove the file suffix and path portion from a path string in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125281/how-do-i-remove-the-file-suffix-and-path-portion-from-a-path-string-in-bash)

Comment: `y=${x##*/}` is simpler and POSIX-compliant.