# How to extract "foo" from "foo-bar-baz" in bash?

Tags: string, bash, text, extract, split

I'm trying to extract `foo` from the string `"foo-bar-baz"` in bash.

Any ideas how to do it using string substitution or something similar (without external tools).

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
$ str="foo-bar-baz"
$ echo ${str%-*}
foo-bar
```

This also not work:

```
$ str="foo-bar-baz"
$ echo ${str#*-}
bar-baz
```

Any ideas how to get just `bar`?

Comment: Cross-posted on Unix+Linux: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/246539/how-to-extract-foo-from-foo-bar-baz-in-bash

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove the file suffix and path portion from a path string in Bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125281/how-do-i-remove-the-file-suffix-and-path-portion-from-a-path-string-in-bash)

Answer (score 1):

```
str="foo-bar-baz"
echo ${str%%-*}
```

Output:

```
foo
```

Comment: See: [Shell Parameter Expansion](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#SEC32) section about `${parameter%%word}`. %% is greedy version of %.

Answer (score 0):

You can also make use of *substring replacement*:

```
str="foo-bar-baz"
foostr=${str//-*/}  ## assign 'foo' to foostr
echo $foostr        ## 'foo'
```

**note:** with the omission of the closing `/`, the replacement string is taken as empty by the shell.

Answer (score 0):

Using Bash regex matching:

```
#!/bin/bash
str="foo-bar-baz"
pat="([^-]*)-([^-]*)-.*"
[[ $str =~ $pat ]]
echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" # foo
echo "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}" # bar
```