# How do I remove the extension of a positional parameter?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal

I want to gunzip a filename, stored in $2, to a specified directory, stored in $3. For example,

if [ -f $2 ]; then

gunzip $2

```
here I want to remove .gz from $2
```

mv $2 $3

fi

so from the terminal command line when running a script I type:

```
-z anotherdirectory/test.txt user/harry
```

because the error says mv: cannot stat ‘backup/test.txt.gz’: No such file or directory.

Thank you everyone!!

Comment: `mv` it first and `gunzip` it second?

Comment: With that, this error appears "gzip: backup/test.txt.gz: No such file or directory". The file gets moved but does not uncompress.

Comment: You'll need to show more of the actual code if you want more specific help. Also if you look around this site you'll find many many examples of parameter expansion being used for this.

Comment: Does `${2%.gz}` not work? Or, more generally, `${2%.*}`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125281/how-do-i-remove-the-file-suffix-and-path-portion-from-a-path-string-in-bash

Answer (score 1):

To remove a single extension, use the `%` suffix deletion operator:

```
mv "${2%.*}" "$3"
```

or if you wanted to only remove `.gz`, you could use:

```
mv "${2%.gz}" "$3"
```

But you could avoid the copy altogether by uncompressing the file directing where you want it to go:

```
gunzip -c "$2" > "$3"
```

The `-c` option tells `gunzip` to write to stdout. Unlike a normal `gunzip`, that does not remove the gzip file, so you would have to `rm` it afterwards.

It's worth noting that `gunzip` understands other extensions such as `tgz`; it will decompress `foo.tgz` to `foo.tar`, not `foo`. So the command which just deletes the extension will not work with all extensions, whereas `gunzip -c` will.

Comment: Beat me by 19 seconds. I will go ahead and remove my post :).

Comment: rici, I believe your second line of code was supposed to read `mv "${2%.gz}" "$3"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 mv $(echo $2 |sed 's/\.gz$//') $3
```

Also you should check this [tutorial about sed](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html)

Comment: Hi its says unexpected end of file when using that line in the above code

Comment: I missed one character in my first answer, sorry. It's already fixed, try again.