# how to name the output file same as input file but different extension after video conversion?

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, video-conversion

I am using this line to batch convert mp4 files to webm files. For all mp4 files i need the output files to be of same name but .webm extension. For example if i have video1.mp4 and video2.mp4 then after conversion i need two files i.e video1.webm and video2.webm. How can i achieve this using bash script?

```
for f in *.mp4; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -c:v libvpx -crf 10 -b:v 1M -c:a libvorbis "$f".webm;  done
```

The above code will change the output file to video1.mp4.webm. Thanks!

Comment: Use suffix removal:  Replace `"$f".webm` with `${f%.mp4}.webm`.

Comment: See [this answer regarding parameter expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33766147/1109017).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this ...

```
for f in *.mp4; 
do 
    ffmpeg -i "$f" -c:v libvpx -crf 10 -b:v 1M -c:a libvorbis "${f%.mp4}".webm;  
done
```

Answer (score 3):

From what I can tell this link is the answer you're looking for. Though you may not need the part that removes the path since you're simply running this within the folder.

Try:

`for f in *.mp4;  do ffmpeg -i "$f" -c:v libvpx -crf 10 -b:v 1M -c:a libvorbis "${f%.mp4}".webm;  done`

[How do I remove the file suffix and path portion from a path string in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125281/how-do-i-remove-the-file-suffix-and-path-portion-from-a-path-string-in-bash)

Edit: Added example; After updating I realize someone else gave the same update.