# How to remove last n character from string in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I have a variable `reponame` in Shell Script(bash) holding a string

```
echo $reponame
"testrepo.git"
```

I want to remove the last 4 character of this string and assign the result to a new variable `repo`

```
echo $repo
"testrepo"
```

How can I do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125281/how-do-i-remove-the-file-suffix-and-path-portion-from-a-path-string-in-bash

Comment: _to remove last n [4] character from string in [bash] shell script_ use `echo ${reponame:0:-4}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to get rid of the `.git` extension. Then the correct expression would be

```bash
repo=${reponame%.*}
```

or

```bash
repo=${reponame%.git}
```

for that very specific case.

For substrings in general, the expression removing last 4 characters would go like

```bash
repo=${reponame:0:-4}
```

Very nice resource on Bash string operations:
https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html

---

For shell in general you might use various approaches such as

```bash
repo=$(echo -n "$reponame" | sed 's/\.git$//')
```

or

```bash
repo=$(echo -n "$reponame" | rev | cut -f 2- -d '.' | rev)
```