# How to copy multiple files from many directories to corresponding directories with different names?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

I have an `apps` folder. I need to copy all the `.env.test` files in each directory inside the `apps` folder to the corresponding `.env` file.

So for example if I have the following 2 directories insided the apps folder:

- client
- server

I need to copy

- `apps/client/.env.test` to `apps/client/.env`
- `apps/server/.env.test` to `apps/server/.env`

I can do that using a for loop like

```bash
for dir in apps/*/; do cp "${dir}.env.test" "${dir}.env"; done
```

But I was wondering if there's a simpler one-liner way maybe using `find -exec cp` or `tee` .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `find`:

```
find . -type f -iname '.env.test' | while read p; do cp "$p" "${p%\.test}"; done
```

This uses the bash [`%` Parameter Expansion operator](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) to remove the `.test` suffix from the path: `"${p%\.test}"`

[How do I remove the file suffix and path portion from a path string in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125281/how-do-i-remove-the-file-suffix-and-path-portion-from-a-path-string-in-bash)

---

Small local demo:

```
$ tree -a
.
└── apps
    ├── client
    │   └── .env.test
    └── server
        └── .env.test

4 directories, 2 files
$
$ find . -type f -iname '.env.test' | while read p; do cp "$p" "${p%\.test}"; done
$
$ tree -a
.
└── apps
    ├── client
    │   ├── .env
    │   └── .env.test
    └── server
        ├── .env
        └── .env.test

4 directories, 4 files
$
```

Comment: Shell variable expansion is not a Regex so the `.` does not need escaping; `cp "$p" "${p%\.test}"` → `cp "$p" "${p%.test}"`

Comment: To handle filenames with odd characters in them, `find` should be using its `-print0` option and `while read p` should be `while IFS= read -rd '' p`.

Comment: Thank you. Your solution inspired me to write this `find apps/*/.env.test | xargs dirname | xargs -I % cp %/.env.test %/.env`

Answer (score 2):

You are tagging the question with bash and zsh, so here is a zsh solution:

```
zmv -C '(apps/*)/.env.test' '$1/.env'
```

To get this working, you have to enable `zmv` in your shell. You can do this (for instance in your .zshrc, or, if you want to have this available in your scripts too, in your .zshenv) by doing an

```
autoload zmv
```

In my setup, I also have a definition

```
alias zcp='zmv -C'
```

so that I can write it as

```
zcp  '(apps/*)/.env.test' '$1/.env'
```

which I find more readable. Note that if .env.test can appear in any depth of your directory tree, you would write instead

```
zcp  '(apps/**)/.env.test' '$1/.env'
```

Comment: Nice solution but I need a generic one that works on any unix-like OS because I'm sharing this snippet as part of a README file, sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: @kerolloz: Can you give me an example of such an OS, where my solution would not wok? I don't see that I have any OS-dependency in my solution.

Comment: The idea is that the user needs to have some customization in his .zshrc file in order to use this line and I can't assume that nor I would like to force users to do this extra step. I also would love the script to work on both bash and zsh. I apologise for any misunderstanding.

Comment: @kerolloz : The user doesn't need to do anything in his startup files. You provide a self-contained zsh script, and this zsh-script is doing the `autoload` and the `zmv -C`. The `alias` is just syntactic sugar and  if you want to safe keystrokes, you don't have to use it in your script. In this way any user can execute your script, as long as he has read permissions for it.